# sed: Extract version number from string

Tags: sed

Input: `adcheck (CentrifyDC 4.4.3-421)`

Desired output: `4.4.3`

What I thought would work:

```
/usr/share/centrifydc/bin/adcheck --version | sed -n '/Centrify DC /,/-/p'
```

But that outputs nothing??

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sed 's/[[:alpha:]|(|[:space:]]//g' | awk -F- '{print $1}' <<< "(CentrifyDC 4.4.3-421)"
```

output: `4.4.3`

Using `[:space:]` to remove extras spaces.

`sed` is used to remove unwanted characters and `awk -F-` means use `-` as field separator

Comment: The pipes inside the bracket expression are not needed, because a bracket expression means "any of these characters." It could be `sed 's/[[:alpha:]([:space:]]//g'`

Comment: every time we pipe so much a kitten dies. `echo | sed | awk` is too much, when `awk` alone can do it.

Answer (score 6):

Your solution does not work because you are trying to use addresses to select a piece of a line, but addresses just select a bunch of lines. Your code `/Centrify DC /,/-/p` would print all lines between one line which contains `Centrify DC` and another line which contains `-`. It does not work inside one line only, however

What you want is to remove everything from the line, except the version number. I would recommend you to group the version number and replace all the content of the line by it:

```
$ echo "adcheck (CentrifyDC 4.4.3-421)" | sed 's/^.*[^0-9]\([0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\).*$/\1/'
4.4.3
```

Here we put the version number in a group with `\([0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\)` and replace all the line by the group (referenced by `\1`).

If your input has more than one line, it may need some tunneling:

```
$ cat file
adcheck (CentrifyDC 4.4.3-421)
another line
still another line
$ sed 's/^.*[^0-9]\([0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\).*$/\1/' file
4.4.3
another line
still another line
```

In this case, pass the `-n` flag to sed for inhibiting the default printing. Then, give an address to the `s///` command (such as `/adcheck (CentrifyDC /`) for guaranteeing that the replacement will occur only in the line which matchs the address. Finally add the `p` flag to the `s///` command  - it will print the line just after the replacement:

```
$  sed -n '/adcheck (CentrifyDC /s/^.*[^0-9]\([0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\).*$/\1/p' file
4.4.3
```

Answer (score 5):

Corrected version of "What you thought would work":

```
/usr/share/centrifydc/bin/adcheck --version | sed 's|.*CentrifyDC \([0-9\.]*\).*|\1|'
```

**Output:**

```
4.4.3
```

Answer (score 4):

### one-line [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) script

```
perl -pe '($_)=/([0-9]+([.][0-9]+)+)/' YOURFILE.TXT
```

or a bit more longer but handles multiple versions:

```
perl -nle 'print $v if ($v)=/([0-9]+([.][0-9]+)+)/' YOURFILE.TXT
```

### examples using the first command line

```
$> V=$(perl -pe '($_)=/([0-9]+([.][0-9]+)+)/'<<<'adcheck (CentrifyDC 4.4.3-421)')
$> echo "$V"
4.4.3

$> V=$(perl -pe '($_)=/([0-9]+([.][0-9]+)+)/' <<< 'dos2unix-8.2.3-beta.zip')
$> echo "$V"
8.2.3

$> echo 'A2 33. Z-0.1.2.3.4..5' | perl -pe '($_)=/([0-9]+([.][0-9]+)+)/'
0.1.2.3.4

$> gcc --version | perl -pe '($_)=/([0-9]+([.][0-9]+)+)/'
4.7.3

$> bash --version | perl -pe '($_)=/([0-9]+([.][0-9]+)+)/'
4.2.45

$> meld --version | perl -pe '($_)=/([0-9]+([.][0-9]+)+)/'
1.6.1

$> uname -a | perl -pe '($_)=/([0-9]+([.][0-9]+)+)/'
3.8.0

$> perl -pe '($_)=/([0-9]+([.][0-9]+)+)/' /etc/issue
13.04
```

**Note:** the first command line extracts the version without the final carriage return (I mean the `\n`). If this is an issue, use the second version or wrap the first command line within `echo`:

```
$> echo $( perl --version | perl -pe '($_)=/([0-9]+([.][0-9]+)+)/' )
5.14.2
```

Unfortunately, if there are multiple lines containing version numbers, these version numbers will be concatenated:

```
$> echo $(gwenview --version | perl -pe '($_)=/([0-9]+([.][0-9]+)+)/' )
```

4.8.44.10.54.10.4

In order to extract one version per line, the one-line script has to be changed:

```
perl -pe 'if(($_)=/([0-9]+([.][0-9]+)+)/){$_.="\n"}'
```

example:

```
$> gwenview --version | perl -pe 'if(($_)=/([0-9]+([.][0-9]+)+)/){$_.="\n"}' 
4.8.4
4.10.5
4.10.4
```

To extract solely the first version number and appending carriage return (I mean new line `\n`), I advice:

```
perl -pe 'if(($v)=/([0-9]+([.][0-9]+)+)/){print"$v\n";exit}$_=""'
```

example:

```
$> gwenview --version | perl -pe 'if(($v)=/([0-9]+([.][0-9]+)+)/){print"$v\n";exit}$_=""'
4.8.4
```

---

For information, my [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) attempt is not as good. Who knows how to obtain the same behavior as my `perl` scripts but using `sed`?

```
sed 's/\([0-9][0-9]*[.][0-9][0-9.]*\)/\n\1/'
```

---

If you think you can improve these scripts, please feel free to post a comment :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution

```
echo "adcheck (CentrifyDC 4.4.3-421)" | sed -nE "s/.*CentrifyDC (([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)-.*).*/\2"/p
```

Let me explain a little bit more on the syntax `(([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)-.*)`

1. The outer round brackets will group the whole version as group 1, e.g. `4.4.3-421`
2. Then the inner round brackets will group the version before hyphen(`-`) as group 2, e.g. `4.4.3`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution in Perl:

```
echo "adcheck (CentrifyDC 4.4.3-421)" | perl -ne 'm/adcheck \(CentrifyDC (.*?)\)/; print "$1\n" '
/usr/share/centrifydc/bin/adcheck --version | perl -ne 'm/adcheck \(CentrifyDC (.*?)\)/; print "$1\n" '
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach using `awk` only:

```
$ echo "adcheck (CentrifyDC 4.4.3-421)" | awk '{sub(/-.*/,"",$3);print $3}'
4.4.3
```

...or perhaps a combination of `cut`:

```
$ echo "adcheck (CentrifyDC 4.4.3-421)" | cut -d' ' -f3 | cut -d'-' -f1
4.4.3
```

Answer (score 0):

For instance, this does the job

```
wget -V|head -n1|sed 's/[[:alpha:]|(|[:space:]]//g' | awk -F- '{print
> $1}'
```

Comment: How does this compare to the accepted answer? Why might someone prefer this approach?