# Extracting Version Number from Strings in a Text File

Tags: numbers, version, extract

Would like to know if it is possible to extract version number from strings in a text file.(Windows & Linux)

For example, Text file contains,

```
some_soft-9.1.2-windows.zip
some_soft-9.2.2-windows.zip
some_soft-10.0.1-windows.zip
some_soft-10.1.2.3-windows.zip
```

and then output of the command should obtain only

```
9.1.2
9.2.2
10.0.1
10.1.2.3
```

So these version number could be processed to download the latest or desired build of the application.

Answer (score 1):

Use regex to extract them

```
([0-9]+.){2,}[0-9]+
```

Comment: Hi Vlad L. I am using a similar regex as yours: `perl -pe '($_)=/([0-9]+([.][0-9]+)+)/'`. Do you think [my version](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19597743/938111) may be simplified? I have spent time trying to find something using [tag:sed]... Do you think we could use something else than [tag:perl]? Cheers ;)

Comment: @olibre sorry, can't say anything about perl. AFAIK Perl has a little bit different regex, but you can use mine with C#. Anyway your regex is as simple as mine :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible and it isn't hard to do it. Try doing some research on how to split a string. In your case, just simply split the string by "-" and get the 2nd element.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use [perl](/questions/tagged/perl), this one-line script does the job:

```
perl -pe '($_)=/([0-9]+([.][0-9]+)+)/'
```

Example using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash):

```
$> V=$(perl -pe '($_)=/([0-9]+([.][0-9]+)+)/' <<< 'some_soft-9.1.2-windows.zip')
$> echo "$V"
9.1.2

$> echo 'A2 33. Z-0.1.2.3.4..5' | perl -pe '($_)=/([0-9]+([.][0-9]+)+)/'
0.1.2.3.4
```

Note this [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) command line extracts the version number without the carriage return.

Please see also [this other SO answer providing many examples and more `perl` scripts depending on your context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19603770/938111).