# How to extract a version number from a string

Tags: regex

I would like to extract the substring `1.9.175` from the string

```
AC_INIT([HDF5], [1.9.175], [help@hdfgroup.org])
```

The solution from [sed: Extract version number from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6655276/sed-extract-version-number-from-string) does not work because of the `5` in `HDF5`;

```
$ echo "AC_INIT([HDF5], [1.9.175], [help@hdfgroup.org])" | sed 's/[^0-9]*\([0-9][\.0-9]*\).*/\1/'
5
```

What is a better alternative?

Comment: Is the version string always surrounded by `[` and `]`?

Comment: @devnull Yes, the formatting is always the same.

Answer (score 0):

A simple regular expression that might work for you is:

```
\[[\d\.]+\]
```

A more complete one:

```
\[\d+(.\d+)+\]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
echo "AC_INIT([HDF5], [1.9.175], [help@hdfgroup.org])" | sed 's/^.*\[\([.0-9]*\)\].*/\1/'
1.9.175
```

Comment: An important thing here: It could match `1....1`, `.....1` or things like that (consecutive dots), just in case there could be invalid inputs... ;)

Comment: There are ways to validate the input also but that complication can be added if there is any real chance of getting invalid input strings.

Comment: Exactly, that's why I included both versions. I just wanted to point that out.